# Convert SortedSet to a TreeMap or ImmutableMap with keys as iterator position

Tags: java, data-structures, java-stream, guava

I've a `SortedSet<MyObject>` and `MyObject` has some `compareTo` logic for `Date`.

```
class MyObject {
   .. many fields
   private Date date;

   @Override
    public int compareTo(MyObject object) {
    .. logic here..
    }    

}
```

I want to convert this `SortedSet` to a `TreeMap` or Guava's `ImmutableSortedMap` with keys as positions of element in `SortedSet`.

E.g

```
0 -> MyObject1
1 -> MyObject2
...and so on
```

I can iterate over the `SortedSet` and put the elements into the new `TreeMap` manually, but i was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do via Streams or Guava libraries / Collection library.

Comment: Note that a map indexed by contiguous integer keys from zero is effectively a `List`. So, `ImmutableList.copyOf(yourSet)` could work.

Comment: Does your class implement Comparable?

Comment: Yes, it does implement `Comparable<MyObject>`

Comment: i don't understand this `with keys as positions of keys`

Comment: Sorry, I meant Position of element in SortedSet

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with a loop.

```
TreeMap<Integer, MyClass> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (MyClass myClass : sortedSet) {
  map.put(map.size(), myClass);
}
```

I find that an awful lot clearer than the streams approach proposed by [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58566075/3788176).

Comment: …and if you want to bring in lambdas at all costs, you can still use `sortedSet.forEach(item -> map.put(map.size(), item));`

Answer (score 0):

Use an effectively final counter variable external to the stream.

Since insertion is in order, you don’t need the final map to be a `TreeMap`; it can be the faster `LinkedHashMap`, whose iteration order is the same as insertion.

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
Map<Integer, MyClass> map = sortedSet.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    x -> counter.getAndIncrement(),
    x -> x,
    (a, b) -> a,
    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

If you desperately need a `TreeMap`, replace `LinkedHashMap` with `TreeMap` in the code above.

Comment: Would not prefer using `AtomicInteger` just for this purpose.

Comment: @novice why? What’s the problem with using a counter like this? Also, note changes to my answer.

Comment: This relies on the processing order being identical to the encounter order. This assumption doesn’t hold for parallel streams, but the specification deliberately makes no guaranty for the processing order of sequential streams either. So you’re paying the price of thread safe constructs (an `AtomicInteger` does not come for free) for a solution not working in parallel and counteracting the intend of the API while still being way more complicated than [a simple loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58570772/2711488)…

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your TreeMap idea exactly what an array would be?

```
MyObject[] myObjects = sortedMap.toArray();
```

Comment: Yes it is kind of now, but i prefer `TreeMap` as it does not grow like List due to index.